# Oracle Accidental Deletion

Tags: oracle, restore

I deleted many table's records accidentally on Oracle 10g, and I have no backup, noarchivelog mode, not open flashback. 
Is it possible to restore data? If yes, how shall I do?

Comment: If you have no backups, no archive logs, no open flashback, you pretty much said "I do not need you (Oracle) to worry about recovery; neither you (Oracle) nor I (Mike) will make mistakes or have any disasters like a disk failure".  I'm sorry you guessed wrong.

Answer (score 4):

How long ago did you delete the data?  If you deleted the data a little less than an hour ago, for example, can you run this query and see if the data is still in UNDO?

```
SELECT *
  FROM some_table AS OF TIMESTAMP systimestamp - INTERVAL '1' hour
```